# Minecraft hunger increasing (bar decreasing) whilst AFK

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've found since the release of Minecraft 1.7, that my hunger bar decreases whilst I'm AFK on my private vanilla server. The wiki page shows a list of actions (e.g walking, running, jumping, etc) that will increase hunger and states that hunger shouldn't increase when not performing these actions.

I've played on three different PCs on my own vanilla server, and I have the problem on every system. Difficulty is on easy, yet I'm loosing one drumstick from my food bar every 20 seconds.

Have I stumbled on a bug, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Can you clarify something, is your hunger bar increasing or decreasing whilst afk? I'm assuming the bar is decreasing but just wanted to verify.

Comment: The bar is decreasing, which means my hunger is increasing. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I think hunger increases over time by a small amount

Comment: I'm pretty sure your hunger bar should decrease while standing still.

Comment: @LTPro, It never has before since I started playing in the 1.2.5 days. But even if it did, one drumstick on the hunger bar every 20 seconds is excessive.

Comment: Yeah, on easy this is definitely not normal.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Would a character grow hungry while standing still, it'd be very hard to play SkyBlock and similar maps. An important part of the gameplay is going into anabiosis and only moving your eyes while you wait for your first melon to grow :-)

Comment: @OrcJMR there is enough time before you starve to wait for your farms to get started, espacially if you are lucky enough to get some apples from the first tree

Comment: @ratchetfreak Still hunger can be an issue if you are unlucky with apples and play less carefully. The point is, I also attest to being able to stand for tens of minutes without losing a single saturation point.

Comment: Rebooting my vanilla server seemed to fix this. Also, I've since upgraded the server from 1.7.2 (IIRC) to 1.7.4 and I've not seen this issue since. I think I was actually using 1.7.4 client on 1.7.2 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick [search](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-40962?jql=affectedVersion%20=%20%22Minecraft%201.7.2%22%20AND%20text%20~%20%22hunger%22) through the Mojang issue tracker returns nothing about the issue you are encountering.

I would submit a bug report with a screenshot or video. Nice find.

Comment: I did search through the issue tracker, but similar issues are all about the hunger bar decreasing too quickly when the player was moving. So I wasn't sure if this was new to 1.7. I couldn't find anything to say it is a new feature, but equally, nothing to 100% confirm it shouldn't happen. I'll report the issue. Thanks.